# Why separating groups using facet-grid and in aes() yield different graph?

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the relationship between income and illiteracy rate between groups of regions. I tried 2 ways and they gave me 2 different results. Now I'm confused I don't know which one is wrong.

data

```
states = cbind.data.frame(state.x77, state.region)
```

code 1

```
m1.plot <- ggplot(states, aes(states$Income, states$Illiteracy))
m1.plot + theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se = F, col="red") +
  facet_grid(. ~states$state.region) +
  labs(x = "Income", y = "Illiteracy rate")
```

[image: graph for code 1]

code 2

```
m1.plot <- ggplot(states, aes(states$Income, states$Illiteracy, col = state.region))
m1.plot + theme_bw() +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(fill = state.region), se=F) + 
  labs(x = "Income", y = "Illiteracy rate")
```

[image: graph for code 2]

As you can see, in graph 1, all lines are negative, but in graph 2, only 1 is negative.

I'm sorry if there has been any same topic, I don't know how to describe this issue so I could not find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: You should use only column names inside of `aes()` and `facet_grid()`. For example, `aes(Income, ...)` not `aes(states$Income)` and `facet_grid(. ~ state.region)` not `facet_grid(. ~ states$state.region)`.

Comment: Thank you, that works out. Can you explain why that happens for me?

Comment: By using X$Y you're feeding ggplot2 all the data vs the groups you think you're working with. Which tutorial have you seen that uses this `$` notation inside the `aes()`? I ask b/c it's been a pretty common issue this semester and I'm assuming there's errant use of it somewhere (fairly high profile) online.

Comment: Also:  reproducible example & output.

Comment: I think it's just a habit when using lm(), using x$y is faster and so far I have not seen any difference in using either so maybe that's why